# Keep Octave open when batch process is finished

Tags: batch-file, octave

I'm using the batch file copied below that opens Octave and executes `myFunction`, which is an interactive routine. When I exit `myFunction`, the Octave session is immediately terminated. Is there a way to keep the Octave window open when `myFunction` is finished, so that I can do further calculations in the same session? I tried `cmd /k` instead of `cmd /c` but this only keeps the terminal window open, not the Octave GUI. Thanks for any advice.

```
@echo off
C:\Octave\Octave-6.2.0\octave.vbs --eval myFunction("'%~1'");
cmd /c
```

Comment: No, `cmd /K` does not keep the `cmd.exe` terminal open, it initiates a new `cmd.exe` instance, which is not the one your batch file runs in. I do not know whether `start "" "C:\Octave\Octave-6.2.0\octave.vbs" --eval myFunction("'%~1'");` helps…

Comment: You are running a Visual Basic script, from a batch file, and doing so using its default script host, which is probably the GUI based `wscript.exe`. I would therefore suggest that you specifically stipulate that you want to use it CLI based host `cscript.exe` instead. `%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe "C:\Octave\Octave-6.2.0\octave.vbs" [args]`. If your Octave Window is not the cmd.exe window, and you really wanted to keep that window open, then we would definitely need to see your `octave.vbs` content, and your question would ideally need to be redirected to a more suitable audience.

Comment: @aschipfl, Same behavior with the batch file modification. I appreciate your clarification of the batch file commands.

Comment: @Compo, thanks for your help. Changing the batch file as you suggested produced the same behavior. I added "--no-gui" to the batch command so that Octave started in the `cmd.exe` window (right...?). It's no problem to run in CLI vs. GUI, would that help? Something else would be needed though, as the CLI window also terminates after `myFunction` is finished. I haven't modified the `octave.vbs` file, everything is default. Thanks again.

Comment: Really helps when you read the documentation for the program. **--eval code Evaluate code and exit when finished unless --persist is also specified.**  I have never used Octave.  Just read the help file.